# Java : Cannot append an object (foreign key) to FormData object

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

i have an error in the frontend, the status code is 400.
i have no backend error.
i am trying to send a POST request to backend based on Spring Boot, while the frontend is an Angular 5 app.
i think the problem is the FormData object does not support object written in JSON. Am i right? if yes how to do?
i want to send a form that contain some input of type text, an input of type file, and an object(foreign key) of type PrestatairesTypes.

#### Here is the Entities :

```
@Entity
public class Prestataires implements Serializable 
{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String nom;
private String email;
private String tele;
private String fax;
private String rib;
private String adresse;
private String taches;
private String photo;

@Lob
private byte[] file;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PRESTATAIRES_TYPES")
private PrestatairesTypes prestatairesTypes;

///Constructors and Getters and Setters 

}
```

#### Here is the second Entity :

```
@Entity
public class PrestatairesTypes implements Serializable 
{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String designation;

//---------------------OneToMany---------------------

@OneToMany(mappedBy="prestatairesTypes")
private Collection<Prestataires> prestataires;

///Constructors and Getters and Setters 
}
```

#### Here is the RestController :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class PrestatairesRestController 
{
@Autowired
private PrestatairesRepository repository;

@RequestMapping(value="/prestataires", 
        method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Prestataires addVilles(Prestataires p,
        @RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile file)
{
    byte[] rawFile = null;
    try{

        rawFile = file.getBytes();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    p.setFile(rawFile);

    return repository.save(p);              
}
```

#### Here is the Prestataires Model :

```
export class PrestatairesModel
 {
id:any;
nom:any;
email:any;
tele:any;
fax:any;
rib:any;
adresse:any;
taches:any;
photo:any;
file:any;

prestatairesTypes:any;

}
```

#### The PrestatairesTypes Model :

```
export class PrestatairesTypeModel
{
id:any;
designation:any;

}
```

#### The Service :

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest} from 
"@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class PrestatairesService
{
 host:string = "http://localhost:8080/";
 constructor(private http:HttpClient)
{

}
uploadFile(model:any)
{


 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('multipartFile', model.file);
 formData.append('nom', model.nom);
 formData.append('email', model.email);
 formData.append('rib', model.rib);
 formData.append('taches', model.taches);
 formData.append('fax', model.fax);
 formData.append('adresse', model.adresse);
 formData.append('tele', model.tele);

 // when i remove this line it's work but i find null in the DataBase
 formData.append('prestatairesTypes', model.prestatairesTypes);


 let params = new HttpParams();

 const options = {
  params: params,
  reportProgress: true,
 };

 const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.host+"prestataires", formData, 
 options);
 return this.http.request(req);
 }
 }
```

#### The Controller :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import {PrestatairesService} from "../../services/prestataires.service";
 import {PrestatairesTypeModel} from "../../modeles/prestatairesType.model";
 import {PrestatairesModel} from "../../modeles/prestataires.model";


@Component({
selector: 'app-ajouter-prestataires',
templateUrl: './ajouter-prestataires.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./ajouter-prestataires.component.css']
})
 export class AjouterPrestatairesComponent implements OnInit {

nom:any = null;
email:any = null;
tele:any = null;
fax:any = null;
rib:any = null;
adresse:any = null;
taches:any = null;
photo:any = null;

selectTypes:any;

typePrestataire:any;

tousLesPrestatairesTypes:any;

modelType:any;

imageURL:string = "../assets/images/MeG.jpg";

fileToUpload:File = null;

modelPrestataires:any;


constructor(private service:PrestatairesService) { }

ngOnInit()
{
  this.getAllTypes();

}

handleFileInput(file:any)
{
  this.fileToUpload = <File>file.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event:any)=>{
    this.imageURL = event.target.result;
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);

}

getAllTypes()
{
  this.service.getAllTypes()
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.tousLesPrestatairesTypes = data;
    }, err=>{

    }, ()=>{

    })
 }

ajouterTypesPrestataires()
{
  this.modelType = new PrestatairesTypeModel();
  this.modelType.designation = this.typePrestataire;

  this.service.ajouterType(this.modelType)
   .subscribe(data=>{


    this.getAllTypes();
    this.modelType = data;

  }, err=>{

  }, ()=>{

  })
 }

 ajouterPrestataires()
 {

  this.modelPrestataires = new PrestatairesModel();
  this.modelPrestataires.nom = this.nom;
  this.modelPrestataires.email = this.email;
  this.modelPrestataires.tele = this.tele;
  this.modelPrestataires.fax = this.fax;
  this.modelPrestataires.rib = this.rib;
  this.modelPrestataires.adresse = this.adresse;
  this.modelPrestataires.taches = this.taches;
  this.modelPrestataires.photo = this.photo;
  this.modelPrestataires.file = this.fileToUpload;

  this.service.getOneType(this.selectTypes)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.modelPrestataires.prestatairesTypes = data;
    }, err=>{

    }, ()=>{
      this.service.uploadFile(this.modelPrestataires)
        .subscribe(data=>{


          this.modelPrestataires = data;

        }, err=>{


        }, ()=>{

        });
    });
```

}

```
 getOneType(id:any)
 {
 this.service.getOneType(id)
  .subscribe(data=>{
    this.modelType = data;
  }, err=>{

  }, ()=>{
      console.log("Complete");
  });

 }

}
```

#### The View :

```
 <div class="right_col" role="main">
 <div class="">
<div class="page-title">
  <div class="title_left">
    <h3>Ajouter Prestataires</h3>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h2>Nouveau Prestataire</h2>
        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
          <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
 role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a routerLink="/prestataires">Retour Prestataires</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">

        <div class="x_content">




            <div id="containerAjouterPrestataires">

            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Raison Social/Nom<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="nom" name="nom" type="text" required 
 class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
12">Email<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" type="email" 
required class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Téléphone<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="tele" name="tele" class="form-control 
 col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Fax<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="fax" name="fax" class="form-control 
  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
   12">RIB<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="rib" name="rib" class="form-control 
   col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
   12">Type<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                  <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="selectTypes" 
   [(ngModel)]="selectTypes">
                      <option selected="selected" *ngFor="let s of 
   tousLesPrestatairesTypes" [value]="s.id" >
                        {{s.designation}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
  toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                      Ajouter Type
                    </button>
                  </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Adresse<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <textarea [(ngModel)]="adresse" name="adresse" 
 class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Adresse"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
 12">Tâches<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <textarea [(ngModel)]="taches" name="taches" class="form- 
 control" rows="3" placeholder="Tâches"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" 
  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data- 
  dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
 </button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ajouter Type 
  Prestataire</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                        <div id="containerType">

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col- 
 xs-12">Nouveau Type<span class="required">*</span></label>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input [(ngModel)]="typePrestataire" 
  name="typePrestataire" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" 
  required>
                          </div>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
   (click)="ajouterTypesPrestataires()">Ajouter</button>

                        </div>

                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
  dismiss="modal" id="fermer">Fermer</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--  /modal -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
  12">Photo/Logo<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input name="multipartFile" class="form-control col-md-7 
  col-xs-12"
                         type="file" required="required"
                         (change)="handleFileInput($event)">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs- 
  12">Image Preview</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <img class="imagePrestataires" [src]="imageURL">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" 
   type="reset">Vider</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
  (click)="ajouterPrestataires()">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

please i need your help. it's a 4 days that i am blocked because of this error.

Comment: i would like to ask some queries before solving the issue  ...1. Have you bind proxy configuration for http connection to spring boot app? ..2.Have you try any other http get request to spring boot-angular app? .

Comment: @this_is_om_vm 1-do you mean the file application.properties ?if yes, yes i did. 2-get request works fine(correct me if i don't understand your questions).thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, i found the solution.
i append only the id of the object PrestatairesTypes, and once at the backend i recover the full object by id and store it via Setter setPrestatairesTypes() and save the Object of type Prestataires. it's works Fine.